# How can I make my systemd service wait for a network interface?

Tags: systemd

I have an upstart script that I am converting to systemd. For this service to start, a certain network interface needs to be available.

This is what I am using in my upstart script:

```
start on (local-filesystems and net-device-added INTERFACE=tun0)
```

What's the systemd equivalent?

Comment: [`Wants=network-online.target`](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.special.html#network-online.target), perhaps? Is there a service which brings up `tun0`?

Comment: `tun0` is brought up by openvpn, but I need the service to be run when `tun0` is up. Is there anyway to specifically target the network interface?

Comment: @F21, Could you check if it is possible to use: `PathExists=/dev/net/tun0` .

Answer (score 0):

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/257888/systemd-wait-for-network-interface-to-be-up-before-running-service

You should be able have a slightly broken version of what you had in the upstart script with something like:

```
Wants=sys-devices-virtual-net-tun0.device
After=sys-devices-virtual-net-tun0.device
```

systemd should generate the `tun0` 'device' file. The only problem is that if the `tun0` device isn't created by openvpn quickly enough, your service start will try to 'start' `sys-devices-virtual-net-tun0.device` which will result in a timeout failure (by default specified by `DefaultTimeoutStartSec` as 90 seconds usually in `/etc/systemd/system.conf`). So it might be best to have something to depend on openvpn and then explicitly check for the `tun0` device, restarting if it is not found:

```
# Wait loosely on openvpn service
Wants=openvpnxxxx.service
After=openvpnxxx.service

# Make sure tun0 is up/active
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c "systemctl is-active sys-devices-virtual-net-tun0.device"
# Keep restarting till tun0 is up
Restart=on-failure
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted this answer - could you give a reason, please?

To me it seems to be correct and working. 
**The only thing to add for those not used to writing unit files:**

_Be sure to place `Wants` and `After` in the `[Unit]` section and `ExecStartPre` and `Restart-on` in the `[Service]` section of your drop-in file.
See https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.unit.html#Wants= and https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.service.html#ExecStartPre=_